# Docker push to Azure container registry fails because authentication expires before it finishes - workaround?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli

Using the Azure CLI on Windows Server 2016 against an Azure container registry (`az login` and `az acr login`)

I'm pushing a large Windows container docker image (>10GB) with `docker push`. It seems the authentication expires before it finishes.

The smaller layers of the image push successfully and finish, but the largest reaches 100% before declaring

`unauthorized: authentication required`

Is there some way to extend the duration of the authentication (`az acr login`) so that the complete push finishes?

Comment: proper layering. questionmark

Comment: @4c74356b41 proper layering is not under my control here, this is Windows server core + the MSDN documented means of installing VS build tools

Comment: why not? have the base in the registry, create a layer with build tools on top of it and push it to the registry, after that you only need to push diffs

Comment: @4c74356b41 the base image is already in the registry (and all those pushes complete successfully separately any way) - the issue is the build tools add a single 50GB+ layer as the result of a one line addition to the Dockerfile. Again - I don't have much control over this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2017#step-5-create-and-build-the-dockerfile

Comment: you dont really need to rebuild build tools on each build

Comment: @4c74356b41 I'm not - this is the first time I've ever built and pushed this image.I don't think your comments here are particularly useful w.r.t the question - if you have an additional workaround I'd be glad to see it added as an answer, but otherwise we should stop here since I don't think this discussion is relevant

Comment: yeah, tldr: this is not needed with proper layering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89660/discussion-between-david-roberts-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: On linux, we solved pushes failing after an hour it with cron, `*/30 * * * * az acr login -n=<name of registry>`, and it works. (Yeah, I know...). You can try running `az acr login` with Windows task scheduler, but I don't know if it will work with Windows user permissions. I also don't know if it will help for a push lasting more than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

A functioning workaround appears to be to ignore `az acr login` entirely, and go straight to `docker login` which actually caches its credentials

I used the workaround of [enabling the administrator account and logging in with that in order to push](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#admin-account) - but this still works with RBAC/user accounts besides the administrator too

Comment: Enabling admin account on azure worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

3 hours is currently the timeout for Azure CLI logins. So, maybe authentication is really timing out on a 10 GB image.

However, in my case, I found that the container's image's repository path needed to all lower case. Once I did this I no longer had authorization issues.

PS> docker images --all
REPOSITORY                                          TAG                 IMAGE ID
my-asp-app                                          latest              a1f5b7c1e076
myFirstContainerRegistry3364629895.azurecr.io/my-asp-app
                                                    v1                  a1f5b7c1e076
myfirstcontainerregistry3364629895.azurecr.io/my-asp-app
                                                    v1                  a1f5b7c1e076